# Representing Complex Vector Spaces as Real Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space with respect to basis $v_{1},...,v_{n}$, and $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation with matrix representation $A$.

Now, consider $V$ as a real vector space with respect to basis $v_{1}, iv_{1},...,v_{n}, iv_{n}$. What is matrix representation of $T$ with respect to this basis $v_{j}, iv_{j}$?

My initial idea was trying to represent each "complex $A$" column $Tv_{j} \rightarrow  v_{1},...,v_{n}$ as two columns for the "real $A$" matrix such that $Tv_{j} + Tiv_{j} \rightarrow  v_{1}, iv_{1},...,v_{n}, iv_{n}$. However, I don't comprehend exactly what the question means by $iv_{j}$ (is it literally $v_{j}$ multiplied by $i$?) or how to represent the new matrix in terms of $A$ (For this, I assume I have to employ something of the form $CAC^{-1}$, where $C$ changes from the real to the complex basis).

I would appreciate some hints on how to proceed from where I am and how to properly interpret the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when $n = 1$? In other words, what does it look like to scale a complex number (a $1$-vector over $\mathbb{C}$) by a complex number (the complex entry of the $1 \times 1$ matrix) *when we represent this over the reals?*

Comment: No need to overcomplicate. You don't need anything except the definition of a representing matrix. By definition, what should be the columns of the matrix? And yes, $iv$ is $v$ multiplied by the scalar $i$. (which is a legit operation since $V$ is a complex vector space)

Comment: @SammyBlack It seems that when I multiply a complex basis $v_{j}$
 by a complex $z=a+bi$
, the equivalent operation on $v_{j},iv_{j}$
 would be $av_{j}+b(iv_{j})$
. So in $n=1$
 case, when complex $v_{j}\rightarrow z$
, we would need real$v_{j}→Re(z)$
 and $iv_{j}→Im(z)$
. Is this the idea?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ be a basis of $V$ in which the matrix of $T$ is $A=(a_{i,j})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}\in\mathscr{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ so that
$$ T(v_j)=\sum_{k=1}^na_{k,j}v_k=\sum_{k=1}^n{\rm Re}(a_{k,j})v_k+\sum_{k=1}^n{\rm Im}(a_{k,j})iv_k $$
and
$$ T(iv_j)=iT(v_j)=-\sum_{k=1}^n{\rm Im}(a_{k,j})v_k+\sum_{k=1}^n{\rm Re}(a_{k,j})iv_k. $$
The matrix of $T$ in the basis $(v_1,iv_1,\ldots,v_n,iv_n)$ is
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
R_{1,1} & \cdots & R_{1,n} \\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
R_{n,1} & \cdots & R_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathscr{M}_{2n,2n}(\mathbb{R}) $$
where
$$ R_{i,j}=\begin{pmatrix}
{\rm Re}(a_{i,j}) & {\rm -Im}(a_{i,j}) \\
{\rm Im}(a_{i,j}) & {\rm Re}(a_{i,j})
\end{pmatrix}. $$